# How to find a minimal planar covering of a graph

Tags: graph-theory, covering-spaces, planar-graphs, infinite-graphs

Every graph has a planar [covering graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_graph). In particular, the [Universal cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_graph#Universal_cover), being a tree, will be planar.

How do we find a *minimal* planar covering $P$ graph of a graph $G$? By minimal, I mean that the only planar covering graph of $G$ that $P$ covers is $P$ itself.

I conjecture that it will involve replacing all $K_5$ and $K_{3,3}$ minors with their minimal planar covering graphs, but I'm not sure.

Notes: If $G$ is planar, then $P = G$. If $G$ has a [planar cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_cover) (a finite planar covering graph), then $P$ will be a planar cover.